# Extjs 6.x Modern : Why template methods like onRender are not working?

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-modern

As mentioned in this Docx [Component Life Cycle](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/guides/core_concepts/components.html) the template methods like initComponent (initialize -> working), [onRender](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/guides/core_concepts/components.html#core_concepts-_-components_-_template_methods) are not invoked when override in the subClass.

```
Ext.define('My.custom.Component', {
extend: 'Ext.Component',
onRender: function() {
    this.callParent(arguments); // call the superclass onRender method

    // perform additional rendering tasks here.
    }
});
```

Is there any change in the Component Life cycle for Modern toolkit? If so what is it?

[Here is the fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1ubl&view/editor)

Comment: I don't find where this is mentioned; can you please add a quote? I will check later today whether this really is the case, IMO you should be able to override `onRender` like any other method.

Comment: check the fiddle with modern and classic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guide you found has just been copied from older versions of ExtJS, where modern toolkit was not included; for example, [the very same guide was already available in 4.2.2](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/components). The concepts do not hold exactly for modern toolkit, although there are similarities.

It seems there is no single event or function that is called for both toolkits. I would recommend to not touch the `onRender` event unless absolutely necessary, because it has no counterpart in modern. Use either the "constructors" (`initComponent`/`initialize`) or listeners (`afterrender`/`painted`).

You would have to ask in the Sencha forum whether these differences will be resolved in ExtJS 6.5.